# How to get and display all child list from Firebase React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, web-applications, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to do something like "blog post" by getting user post, push it onto firebase and then get it back to display on element.
Here is a part of my code

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        title: '',
        story: '',
        date: ''
    };
}

componentDidMount(){
    const rootRef = firebase.database().ref();
    const post = rootRef.child('post').orderByKey();


   post.once('value', snap => {
       snap.forEach(child => {
           this.setState({
               date: child.key,
               title: child.val().title,
               story: child.val().story
           })
       });
   });

}
```

on render()

```
<div className="post">
      <h3>{this.state.date}</h3>
      <h2>{this.state.title}</h2>
      <p>{this.state.story}</p>
</div>
```

on firebase database

[image]

get this result

[image]

**So how should I do to display the element like the result pattern and can display all of data list.**

Answer (score 4):

I get the correct result by doing like this

```
constructor(props){
super(props);
this.state = {
        title: [],
        story: [],
        date: [],
        post: '',
    };
};}

componentDidMount(){
const rootRef = firebase.database().ref();
const post = rootRef.child('post').orderByKey();

     post.once('value', snap => {
       snap.forEach(child => {
           this.setState({
               date: this.state.date.concat([child.key]),
               title: this.state.title.concat([child.val().title]),
               story: this.state.story.concat([child.val().story])
           });

           const postList = this.state.date.map((dataList, index) =>
                <p>
                    {dataList}
                    <br />
                    {this.state.title[index]}
                    <br />
                    {this.state.story[index]}
                    <hr />
                </p>

            );

            this.setState({
                post: postList
            });
       });
   }); }
```

on render()

```
<div className="diary">

  <ul>{this.state.post}</ul>

</div>
```

the result.
[image]

Comment: is this the traditional way to render your content from a firebase database? im new to reactjs & firebase but this was most helpful to me, but also seems very complicated...