# react firebase can't able to print child values?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-router, react-redux

I want to print firebase child values in some systematic order. If I have more than 1 child node then all the child node with it's key and value should be printed.

My firebase database:
[image]

Now my code:

```
import React,{Component} from "react";
import LogInNavbar from './LogIn_Navbar';
import Footer from './Footer';
import HomePageContent from './HomePage_Content';
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import firebase from 'firebase';
import {withRouter} from "react-router-dom";
import {bindActionCreators} from "redux";
import {action_getdata} from '../actions';
import { db } from '../firebase/firebase';
class LoginHome extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      Hemoglobin:[],
      BloodP:[],
      BloodG:[],
      Diabetic:[],
      Name:''
    };
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    console.log(this.props.user);
    if(this.props.aadharNumber === ''){
      db
      .ref(this.props.quali+'/'+this.props.uName)
      .on('value', snapshot=>{
        this.props.action_getdata({
          aadharNumber: snapshot.val().aadharNumber,
          biometricImage: snapshot.val().biometricImage,
          email: snapshot.val().email,
          firstName: snapshot.val().firstName,
          lastName: snapshot.val().lastName,
          mobileNumber: snapshot.val().mobileNumber,
          password: snapshot.val().password,
          qualification: snapshot.val().qualification,
          uName: snapshot.val().uName
        });
      });
    }
    const rootRef = firebase.database().ref('Reports/');
    const post = rootRef.child('yashchks87').orderByKey();

         post.once('value', snap => {
           snap.forEach(child => {
               this.setState({
                   Name: this.state.Name.concat([child.key]),
                   BloodP: this.state.BloodP.concat([child.val().BloodP]),
                   BloodG: this.state.BloodG.concat([child.val().BloodG]),
                   Hemoglobin: this.state.Hemoglobin.concat([child.val().Hemoglobin]),
                   Diabetic: this.state.Diabetic.concat([child.val().Diabetic])
               });

               const postList = this.state.Name.map((dataList, index) =>
                    <p>
                        {dataList}
                        <br />
                        {this.state.BloodP[index]}
                        <br />
                        {this.state.BloodG[index]}
                        <hr />
                    </p>

                );

                this.setState({
                    post: postList
                });
           });
       });


  }
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <LogInNavbar />
        <div className='p-4'>
          <div className='pt-4'/>
          <h1 className='pt-4'>Your history something like this:</h1>
          <ul>{this.state.post}</ul>
        </div>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
function mapStateToProps(state)
{
  return{
    user:state.authentication.user,
    aadharNumber: state.getdata.aadharNumber,
    biometricImage: state.getdata.biometricImage,
    email: state.getdata.email,
    firstName: state.getdata.firstName,
    lastName: state.getdata.lastName,
    mobileNumber: state.getdata.mobileNumber,
    password: state.getdata.password,
    qualification: state.getdata.qualification,
    uName: state.getdata.uName,
    quali: state.getdata.quali
  }
}
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
  return{
    action_getdata:bindActionCreators(action_getdata,dispatch)
  }
}
export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(LoginHome));
```

As you can see in my above code I want to print all values in formatted way. You can also see for more details at this question, I try the way described over there, but can't able to get anything and falls in error.

[How to get and display all child list from Firebase React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45001916/how-to-get-and-display-all-child-list-from-firebase-react).

And my error is:

[My error picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYsCE.png)
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not coming from your `render` function rather from your state initialisation where you had `Name: '' // string not array` and javascript being a very funny language should have warned you when you tried to

```
this.setState({
  Name: this.state.Name.concat([child.key]),
 .....
```

that Name is a string not an array, but instead JS type casted it to string

```
'abcd'.concat(['efg']) // 'abcdefg' :-)
```

make your initial Name an array to avoid this

Comment: Firstly, Thanks. I changed it and that works perfectly that error is gone. But I can't able to fetch values from firebase and in console it shows undefined.

Comment: Where and what exactly is it showing undefined in the code?

Comment: I write something like: 
componentDidUpdate(){

Comment: I added below code and it shows undefined:
componentDidUpdate(){
    console.log(this.state.BloodG);
    console.log(this.state.BloodP);
  }

Comment: It's hard for me to tell, but are you sure your firebase properly configed and is return data? `[ ].concat(undefined) // [undefined]`

Answer (score 0):

One issue that I see is that it seems you are trying to reference 'Reports' but you did not set the initial state for it. This will return undefined if you try to reference it.
You are also declaring values of an object as arrays. 
 Try this:

```
class LoginHome extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      Reports:[],
      Name:''
    }
  }
```

Also, "Name, BloodP, and BloodG" are not children of 'yashchks87'